# hibernate.cfg.xml not found when run as executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jar, executable-jar

I am new to Hibernate.
When I run my Hibernate program using Eclipse, it is able to find **hibernate.cfg.xml** file.
I put that file into **src/main/resources** folder.
But when I create **executable jar** and run my program using
**java -jar SQ.jar**
It is giving me following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.moodys.sonarqube.ExtractSQData.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:20)
    at com.moodys.sonarqube.ExtractSQData.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
    at com.moodys.sonarqube.ExtractSQData.SQ.getProjectDB(SQ.java:266)
    at com.moodys.sonarqube.ExtractSQData.SQ.extractSQDataToDB(SQ.java:76)
    at com.moodys.sonarqube.ExtractSQData.SQ.main(SQ.java:59)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1405)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1427)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1414)
    at com.moodys.sonarqube.ExtractSQData.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:14)
    ... 4 more
```

Following is the code where I load my **hibernate.cfg.xml** file

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Please advise me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the full path while configure it.
You can try this.

```
return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

or

return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Hi Riddi,
Thanks for your reply but this is not working :(

Comment: Yo can try by giving the full path of cfg file while configuring

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one also if you are using hibernate 4.3+

```
configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceBuilder.build());
```